# Find a string with most unique characters in array

Tags: scala

Given a list of strings: `List("abcdefghijklmnoprstuwxy", "aabcdfffgg" ....`
Return a list of  strings with most unique characters ( if there are several strings like that, print the only  shortest ones).
I did something like this using reduce, but it don't know if it even works well and also i didn't cover the requirement to print the shortest one, if there are several strings of most unique characters. :

```
val string = lst.map(x => x.toLowerCase()).reduce((x,y) => if (x.distinct.size > y.distinct.size) x else y)
```

Comment: How to make this work: lst.map(x => x.toLowerCase()).filter((a,b) => a.distinct.size > b.distinct.size) ??

Comment: You can use the built-in `maxByOption` method like this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/ODCDd2cPTy2TKHvEhqDzGg